# PHP Errors inside of html blocks

Tags: php

This has two questions wrapped into 1.

1) If my php script has an error inside of `<div style="<?php echo $1; ?>"`, how can I make the php error handler to close this quote? I have already customized the error handler, but unfortunately, everything appears inside of the `<div style="...`

2) I have a php fatal error handler in the register shutdown function, is it possible to clear the rest of the buffer from the page (ie. display only the error message)?

Thanks,

Elijah

Update:

None of these answers are related at all to my question, so evidently I have been unclear.

Take, for example, the following code examples (one per line)

```
<div><?php count('abc'); ?>
<div style="<?php echo count('abc');
```

In the first case, the error message will print fine. In the second case, the error message will start to appear inside the div. If there is a " in the error message html (from a custom handler), then the tag will be closed somewhere like this (but it opens again at the closing of the new "):

```
<div style="<div style="asasdf">errortext</div>
```

Is there a way to force the browser to close these tags that will work in the normal case also? I do not think that there is, but sometimes something is possible somehow in cases like this.

Comment: Variable name can't start with a number! `$1` is a syntax error.

Comment: for #2 add die(); at the end of the function

Comment: you mean if `$1` is not set? or does `$1` contain the custom error? the register shutdown function only happens when the script finnishs or hits a fatal error, perhaps your looking for the [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) defined to your own error handler, also Martins Briedis is right

Answer (score 2):

Important rule of thumb: **Do not mix application logic with the presentation layer.**

Therefore: First do the error checks, and then render the page output.

Comment: If the error is in the presentation logic, how should he go about catching that before rendering it?

Comment: he can assign a variable beforehand so that he can catch the error before headers are sent to the browser and handle it as he wishes

Comment: I think his issue is *how can he ensure the error message is visible if he accidentally mistypes a variable name in the presentation logic, especially if it's within an HTML attribute value.*

Comment: an alternative would be to use a template engine which parses the contents of the presentation contents before displaying them

Comment: In this case, there is no ability for me to modify the structure of the code towards a template as a) this is a shared project and b) this is not so important that it would justify the downsides of using a template

what I did, for a trial was to set ob_start(); and then clear the buffer upon my register_shutdown function if there was no fatal error. For non-fatal errors, I have no solution.

This worked fine for me, until there was an encoding issue on a firefox browser related to gzip compression and now the code only runs on my private but not shared server.

Comment: If this is a shared project, seperating application logic and  the presentation is even more important. But, it's the decision of the whole team then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, handle the value before the block, example:

```
if($1 == 'Somevalue')
$myStyle = 'font-size:18px'; else
$myStyle = 'anotherStyle';
```

then in your block use `$myStyle`

`<div style="$myStyle"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here may simply be that your variable name starts with a "1" (a numeric character). `$1` is not a legal variable name.

Try using something like `$var1`.